# Can Chrome Extensions access data (chrome.storage API) from other chrome extensions installed?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am building a Chrome Extension and this extension stores data locally via the chrome.storage API. I was wondering if other Chrome-extensions could potentially sniff the data stored for that extension, or can the extension itself only access this data?

Comment: The only ways for other extensions to read that storage are 1) an extension as a devtools panel opened on your extension's page (like Storage Area Explorer), 2) chrome.debugger API which will show a warning under the address bar.

Comment: Will regular `debugger` API access be able to sniff settings from another extension which has a content script injected? @wOxxOm

Comment: What is a `regular debugger API access`? AFAIK chrome.debugger can attach to both an isolated world and an extension page.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for answering! What about the running background.js, the messaging system between popup.js <-> background.js is only meant for popup, other extension could not send/receive messages from my backgroundJS unless I add externalMessages into the backgroundJS right? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, extensions are fully isolated.